# What does 二货朋友 mean?

Tags: grammar, word

Another Weibo post. This one has a lot that i dont understand. I think 有天二货朋友看到我的说说 Means “one day two friends said to me..." But that structure is very strange. I would have written 有一天两位朋友对我说。。。is this some kind of slang?

The rest is difficult for me to translate as well. My take: one day two friends sais to me, compare girls to clothes, young women are brands that you can buy! They adamantly commented: expensive brands also need no money!

有天二货朋友看到我的说说， 就算女人如衣服，姐也是你穿不起的牌子！ 果断在评论里说：“再贵的牌子，试穿也是不要钱的！「转」更多精彩关注@女神阁

Comment: 二货 an internet slang, means **idiotic**. However usually, it has no derogatory sense -- it's just teasing.

Comment: I think "我的说说" refers to the blogger's post and "二货朋友" is written in jest to address her friends as inferior persons similar to secondhand goods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

G.Depardieu is Jean Reno's 二货朋友 in Tais-toi. Joey Tribbiani is the 二货朋友 in Friends. As Stan mentioned above, 二货 is an affectionate way to refer to a friend that may not be a genius but everyone loves him. 二: stupid. 货: buddy/man/stuff. More usage: 吃货 is one that admires good food(in a less graceful way). A refined 吃货 is a 美食家(gourmet).

女人如衣服 means "women are like clothes". It's usually used with another sentence, 兄弟如手足, which means "brothers are like limbs". If you ruined your garments, you can always buy new ones. But a lost limb is a pain that lasts. And here brothers mean true friends. But this joke is just using 女人如衣服 in its literal meaning.

姐也是你穿不起的牌子！Here 姐 is just a way to call oneself. To further the comparison 女人如衣服, she says that I'm a brand that you can't afford.

再贵的牌子，试穿也是不要钱的！ I'm afraid there're a lot to cover if you want to make sens of this, so I will just write down the translation: No matter how expensive clothes are, it's always free to try them on!

This is supposed to be a joke, but frankly I didn't get it.

Comment: Wow this is some deep native level slang... Never would have guessed 二 could mean something offensive. Always thought of it as simply the number two :)

Comment: Offtopic: Totally love Tais-toi. Have watched it several times :).

Comment: This girl considers herself superior and normal people are not expected to marry her. The comment is  saying: Just like I can't afford a brand but can try it for free, I'm not qualified enough to marry you but I still have a chance 'try' you for free. It actually doesn't make much sense, just an offensive reply to the arrogant girl.

Comment: @Yaboot The intention is not to refer to "marriage" but "relationship". If you have enough knowledge at popular Chinese culture at the moment, you'll understand the implication. Basically, the guy was offended by the girl and replied that even he can't have a relationship her, there's no problem "f*ing" with her. Sorry for the wording but this better reflects the original context.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to emphasize that 二货 and especially the *adjective* part 二 used to be offensive until recent years.

「二货」comes from the *adj* 二 and 货(goods, commodity, entity). 二 used to be interpreted as *stupid* or even *intellectually under-developed (due to disease)*, especially in some regional dialects (so watch out and don't use this phrase in rural areas). But currently on the cyber space 二 is not considered offensive and tend to mean *silly* (I assume you can distinguish *stupid* & *silly*).

So 二货朋友 means *a silly friend*.

Comment: I second to this. I've heard the usage of 二货 since I was small in the early 90's and it was definitely a derogatory term back then.

Comment: As with many terms, overuse by youth and/or online has reduced its impact there, but it remains offensive elsewhere so be very careful where you say it.